Is there any way to find Steklov eigenvalues of graph with the help of certain kind of metric in spectral graph theory?
From Fan R.K. Chung's book Spectral graph theory (Regional Conference Series in Mathematics. 92. Providence, RI: American Mathematical Society (AMS), pp. xi+207 (1997), ISBN:0-8218-0315-8, MR1421568, Zbl 0867.05046), I got aware of the fact that we can find the Neumann eigenvalue of a subgraph with the help of certain kind of metric. I am investigating if the same thing is true for Steklov Eigenvalues on graph.
